# How to make Jupyter SQL highlighted cells executable?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Piggy backing below answer.
[adding syntax highlighting to Jupyter notebook cell magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641362/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-jupyter-notebook-cell-magic)

Added below in my **jupyter/custom/custom.js**.

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function(codecell) {
  codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_text/x-mssql'] = {'reg':[/^%%sql/]} ;
  Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', function(){
  Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map(function(cell){
      if (cell.cell_type == 'code'){ cell.auto_highlight(); } }) ;
  });
});
```

This makes the SQL syntax highlight that is true, but I cannot execute the cell itself due to
"UsageError: Cell magic `%%sql` not found.".
[image]

Any idea how make it actuallly executable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `%load_ext sql` before using the `%%sql` magic cell.

[image]

[See ipython-sql reference](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-sql/)